# Errors with If statement

Tags: java, if-statement

Okay, so i am having some issues with my code. First the positive. Everything works as i want to. So firstly, i want my program to search a text file for some keyword or synonyms of the keyword. That works, but my issue lies with keywords that are not found.  my if(found) statement  never seems to be reached. I tried using debugger but i haven't seen what the issuse is.

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException, IOException {
    /* Initialization */
    List<DicEntry> synonymMap = populateSynonymMap(); // populate the map

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = null;
    /* End Initialization */
    System.out.println("Welcome ");
    System.out.println("What would you like to know?");

    System.out.print("> ");
    input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    String[] inputs = input.split(" ");

    for (String ing : inputs) {
        boolean found = false;

        for (DicEntry entry : synonymMap) { // iterate over each word of the
                                            // sentence.

            if (entry.pattern.matcher(input).matches()) {
                found = true;
                // System.out.println(entry.key);
                parseFile(entry.key);

                System.out
                        .println(" Would you like to update this information ? ");
                String yellow = scanner.nextLine();
                if (yellow.equals("yes")) {
                    removedata(entry.key);
                    break;
                }
                if (yellow.equals("no")) {

                    System.out.println("Have a good day");
                    break;
                }
            }


        if (found) {

                    Writer();


                // break;
            }

        }       
            // break;

}   



}
   }
```

Assume that the *Writer(),removedata(),parsefile()* methods work, can someone help?

Comment: Can you describe your interaction with your program? Because if anyone types `yes` or `no`, it will break out of the loop (at least going by the way your code is written; the `if` seems to be inside the `for` loop).

Comment: Not quite sure what the very end result of this is supposed to be, but it could be caused by your later if conditions being met; your `if(found)` line is within your `for()` loop, so if you break the loop, your if is never reached.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing  the below code out of the `for` loop. i assume it will work

```
if (found) {

                    Writer();

               }
```

Also change

```
if (yellow.equals("yes")) {
                    removedata(entry.key);
                    break;
                }
                if (yellow.equals("no")) {

                    System.out.println("Have a good day");
                    break;
                }
```

to

```
if (yellow.equals("yes")) {
                    removedata(entry.key);
                    break;
                }
               else if (yellow.equals("no")) {

                    System.out.println("Have a good day");
                    break;
                }
```

Comment: Don't forget to declare the variable outside of the loop if you do this!

Comment: @Lalit This way still does not work. For some reason the if(found) is not reached..

Answer (score 0):

If you answer anything other than yes or no, the if(found){} will be reached.
Or you could put if(found){} loop outside for statement.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need if (found) block. You can directly call Writer(); just after removedata(entry.key);

Try this, hope this will work

```
if (yellow.equals("yes")) 
 {
  removedata(entry.key);
  Writer();
  break;
}
```

Comment: I wanted a if(found) block to show that if some input is not found in the loop then i call the writer method . But your way doesn't work